# Unit testing a Vue.js/Node.js app with Websockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I have a Vue (3.0.3) project that pairs with a Node.js server. How would I go about unit testing this? This is for a game that uses web-sockets to communicate.

Comment: Try mocha, chai, chai-http. Using chai-http you can test any http endpoint also websockets.

Comment: For readers coming to this page: if one is **unit** testing something, one would not run websocket connections at all. Such connections would be stubbed out or mocked, and the data that flows to/from the connection would be tested based on mock responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend looking into [Jest](https://jestjs.io). It's an extremely powerful JavaScript testing framework with many similarities to the excellent [Spock](http://spockframework.org) testing framework for Java.

Comment: I know about Jest. It seems like chai-http is way to go.